# Exiting apps in HTML5 &Jquery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, cordova

I am trying to create a mobile webapp using HTML5 and JqueryMobile. I want to use one Exit button on which the app should be exited. I already tried window.close() and self.close().
That is not working.

Or it will be okay...back button of device automatically handles the exit option of app?
Anyone have idea about this?

Answer (score 3):

On Android you can use...

```
navigator.app.exitApp();
```

As far as I'm aware, iOS does not offer a way to programmatically exit an application.

But really, you don't need an exit button.  The devices that the app will run on all have home and/or back buttons, which are the correct way to "exit" apps.  Let the OS decide what to do with it, not the user.

Comment: You just said above that you are doing HTML5 mobile webapp development... so which is it?  But I agree with this answer, exit buttons in mobile apps are against design best practices, instead you should be using the back button/home button and letting the OS control it.

Comment: @ajitksharma If you are using HTML5, Javascript and Cordova then you are not doing native app development.

Comment: yeah actually i meant i am not doing native, it was by mistake.sorry

Comment: The above code is Javascript, for use with Cordova, but as we agree, you're better off without it :)

Answer (score 1):

Back button is used in navigation so it will just navigate you to previous page in your web view.
You need to handle it yourself in back button handler and call

```
navigator.app.exitApp()
```

when you need to exit app.
You can add back button handler with command:

```
document.addEventListener('backbutton', backbuttonHandler, false);
```